# Cannot find button in bootstrap-vue modal (b-modal) int test

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-vue, vue-test-utils

I want to test modal behavior in my test case.

1. open modal by button on page (isVisible false=> true)
2. close modal by button on modal (isVisible trye=> false)

First step is ok, but 2nd step is failed. I can find modal by ref, but I can't find the button on modal.

Home.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <b-button id='button-open' @click="open">open</b-button>
    <b-modal
      ref="modal-ref"
      hide-footer
    >
      <b-button id='button-close' @click="close">close</b-button>
    </b-modal>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    open() {
      console.log('open');
      this.$refs['modal-ref'].show();
    },
    close() {
      console.log('ok');
      this.$refs['modal-ref'].hide();
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

home.spec.js

```js
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { createLocalVue, mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue';
import Home from '@/views/Home.vue';

describe('Boostrap Modal', () => {
  it('open and close modal', async () => {
    const localVue = createLocalVue();
    localVue.use(BootstrapVue);
    const wrapper = mount(Home, {
      localVue,
      attachToDocument: true,
    });

    const open = wrapper.find('#button-open');
    const modal = wrapper.find({ ref: 'modal-ref' });
    expect(modal.vm.isVisible).to.equal(false);
    open.trigger('click');
    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
    console.log(modal.exists());
    expect(modal.vm.isVisible).to.equal(true);

    // find it from modal
    const close = modal.find('#button-close');
    expect(close.exists()).to.equal(true);
    close.trigger('click');

    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
    expect(modal.vm.isVisible).to.equal(false);
    wrapper.destroy();
  });
});
```

I cannot figure out why close-button cannot be found.
(`close.exists()` => false)

Comment: how to fix : https://github.com/sdf611097/problems/commit/e30ac2c1ca51c23fedce27429475291b96a6c949

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modal's are portalled by default to be appended to the `<body>` element. and will not be inside your wrapper when shown.

You need to query the `document` to find your button:

```js
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { createLocalVue, mount, createWrapper } from '@vue/test-utils';
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue';
import Home from '@/views/Home.vue';

describe('Boostrap Modal', () => {
  it('open and close modal', async () => {
    const localVue = createLocalVue();
    localVue.use(BootstrapVue);
    const wrapper = mount(Home, {
      localVue,
      attachToDocument: true,
    });

    const open = wrapper.find('#button-open');
    const modal = wrapper.find({ ref: 'modal-ref' });
    expect(modal.vm.isVisible).to.equal(false);
    open.trigger('click');
    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
    console.log(modal.exists());
    expect(modal.vm.isVisible).to.equal(true);

    // find it from modal close button in the document
    const closeElement = document.getElementById('button-close');
    expect(closeElement).toBeDefined();
    const closeWrapper = createWrapper(closeElement);
    expect(closeWrapper.exists()).to.equal(true);
    expect(closeWrapper.is('button')).toBe(true);
    closeWrapper.trigger('click');

    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
    expect(modal.vm.isVisible).to.equal(false);
    wrapper.destroy();
  });
});
```

Comment: BTW, why you await 2 nextTick?

Comment: Portalling adds an extra delay (all updates to the modal will happen in a nextTick as they are transfered to the portal), plus need time to allow the transitions to happen.

Comment: dude, you're a genius. you saved me from a world of hurt. many thanks.

Comment: The part which creates wrapper from an element fixed my issue. This solusion is still relevent and thanks for sharing.